# CiviMail html format splits images and text

Tags: civimail

On the preview the email looks as it should, with pictures and formatted text, when i test email all of the pictures will appear above the text completely separated.

Comment: how are you aligning the pictures? most of the css positioning is removed on email clients, but not on the preview

Comment: converting a pdf for it so i'm not too sure :/

Answer (score 3):

Most email clients only accept a limited subset of html tags, and many do not respect `style` attributes. If your image markup looks like `<img style="float:right"...` try changing it to `<img align="right"...`

Comment: i don't have any styles like that but there are alot of style like this:
<div id="id_1" style="margin
style="font-weight: bold; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 32px;
style="float: left; margin:
Is this fixable?

Comment: That's not markup that will work well as an email, sorry. Maybe look at a different way of writing markup than whatever pdf-auto-convert you were using.